# The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:Finchley.M8

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am getting below error and unable to understand the exact root cause, I have tried many things, such as I have cleaned up my `.m2` repository and rebuilt. But build is failing due to below error. And I also have reinstalled `Maven` as well and also I tried with different plugins and repositories in my `pom.xml` but still having same issue.
Please let me know solution

- Error message:

  ```
  Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.github.ulisesbocchio:
  jasypt-spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0: The following artifacts could not be 
  resolved: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-
  dependencies:pom:Finchley.M8 (absent): Could not transfer artifact 
  org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:Finchley.M8 from/to 
  spring-releases (https://repo.spring.io/libs... status code: 401, reason phrase: (401)
  ```
- I want to build my application

Comment: what does your pom look like? As per https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/14/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-january-2023 , repo.spring.io does not serve releases anymore, so you should have an entry in your pom to get milestone releases https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Artifactory . Or can't you simply rely on released versions?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-repo-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Repository - Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```